# Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ';'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
Line 52: <li>
Line 53:    <div class="short">
Line 54:        <div class="short_holder">
Line 55:            if (latest.blahblah == PostManager.blahblah){
Line 56:               <a href="@(latest.URL)" title="@(latest.Title)">
```

In my asp.net mvc 3 apps I got error in my views. it's looking fine to me.

Comment: Its somewhere else. Show us your view.

Comment: check closing bracket for if.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hdyz4dw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

if(...) -> @if(...)
if in a div without @ will be html text